# Cannot save Firestore data into global struct

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Swift and I'm having trouble sending data in my Firestore database to my global data structure (array in a struct). I looked through many similar questions and tried their solutions for hours to no avail, so please help me. I am totally stuck.

I somewhat understand that the problem lies in the initializeDocs() section of my code being asynchronous. I've tried DispatchQueue.main.async as well as completion handlers (although I'm not sure if the way I did them was correct), but I'm still getting the same result- i.e. the Firestore data is not being saved in the struct and I am instead getting back an empty array when I try calling them in my init function. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
struct booksStruc{
    static var modelAry = [Model]()
    static var titles: [String] = []
    static var authors: [String] = []
    static var years: [String] = []
    static var emails: [String] = []
    static var capacity = 0
    static var counter = 0
}

init(logo:String, title:String, author:String, year:String, email:String, desc:String) {

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    ref = Database.database().reference()

    super.init()

    group.enter()

    DispatchQueue.main.async{
        self.initializeDocs()
        group.leave()
    }


    self.logoTitle = logo
    self.imageTitle = title
    self.imageAuthor = author
    self.imageYear = year
    self.imageEmail = email
    self.imageDesc = desc

    print("end of init's titles are ", booksStruc.titles)
    print("end of init's capacity is ", booksStruc.capacity)
}

func initializeDocs() {

    db.collection("books").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in

        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            let downloadGroup = DispatchGroup()

            downloadGroup.enter()
            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                        let dictionary = document.data()
                        booksStruc.capacity = document.data().capacity
                        //print("capacity is: ", capacity)

                        for(key, value) in dictionary{

                            if(key == "title"){
                                booksStruc.titles.append(value as! String)
                            } else if(key == "author"){
                                booksStruc.authors.append(value as! String)
                            } else if(key == "year"){
                                booksStruc.years.append(value as! String)
                            } else if(key == "email"){
                                booksStruc.emails.append(value as! String)
                            }
                            //print("\(key) : \(value)")
                        }
                }
                downloadGroup.leave()
            }
        }

    }

    print("titles are ", booksStruc.titles)
    print("capacity is ", booksStruc.capacity)
}
```

Comment: What do you expect will happen? `initializeDocs` runs asynchronously, so your prints are executing before the data is returned. Why did you use DIspatchGroups? If your intent was to make the main queue wait for the group to complete, that's not what your code is doing. You can check the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup) for guidance on how to use DispatchGroups, but I don't think that's really what you want here.

Comment: Yes, my intent is indeed to make init to wait for initializeDocs to complete. I know that's not what my code is doing. I tried using dispatchgroups since that's what other answers on this site proposed. But it's not working. So I'm not sure if the docs for the dispatch groups would be helpful.